# Dynamically assign columns when crawling a product detail page?

Tags: web-crawler, import.io

I'm completely new to import.io and stack overflow, please be kind to me.

I'm trying to crawl product detail pages of an online shop that sells jewelry and find this kind of feature listing on the page:

**Features**

**Gender**
   Men

**Technical Style**
    Quartz

**Material**
    Stainless stell

etc.

Is it possible to train the crawler to dynamically extract the **bold** text as column name and the not bold text as column value?
i.e. Column "gender" has value "men", etc. The assumption is that on other product detail pages the features might not start with "gender"

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but I think these would work:

1. Train one column by selecting all bold texts and the another column with the corresponding value by using xpaths.
2. Train it all as one row so it would always select all the features.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible :)

1. You make a col and give it the name - Gender
2. Then you click or highlight the data you want - Men

If you feel like its not working, you can go advanced, and use an xpath.

**How to:**

To do this you click on the data type, next to the column name, in the image below you can see its the pink text that says "Text" located in the left hand pane, on the right hand side.

[image]

Then when you see an option to "show advanced settings" which you should click.

[image]

When you are there, you can add an "xpath Override" and put this in there.

```
//*[text()="Gender"]/following-sibling::*
```

That tells import.io "exactly" where the data is based on a set of rules you can put in there.

[image]

This article will have some help: 
http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/368731-webinar-5-tips-and-tricks

This one will find all mentions of the word gender on the page, and then looks at the thing next to it in the HTML and puts that in your col.